# jQuery nothing showing up under 3rd tab

Tags: jquery

In the 3rd tab 'Contact' I cant get anything to show up, Im trying to add 'Hello'
but its not adding, am I missing a div or something? I cannot see where the issue is.
In future I am going to make backups!

online example:
http://www.taffatech.com/Demo.html

body code:

```
<body background="images/back.jpg">

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Register new player!">
<form action="#" method="post">
<p>Username: <input id="Username" type="text">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Male: <input     type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> &nbsp;&nbsp; Female: <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> <br><br>
Password: <input id="Password" type="password">  <br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D/O/B: <input id="datepicker" type="text"><br><br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Email: <input id="Email" type="text">  
     <br></p> 
    <div style="float:left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="  Submit  " /></div>
      </form>
    <div style="float:right"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" /> <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<Font SIZE ="4"> Copyright 2013</font></div>
</div>

 <div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Main</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Play</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">

<div id="accordion">
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<div>
<p>
Hello and welcome we are currently in development, check back soon!
</p>
</div>
<h3>Games</h3>
<div>
<p>
As of yet we are just testing and getting used to jQuery and jQuery UI!!
</p>
</div>
<h3>About</h3>
<div>
<p>
My name is Wayne Daly and I study Computer Science in CIT.
I'm interested in:
</p>
<ul>
  <li>Making games</li>
  <li>Designing visual programs</li>
  <li>Coding!</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>Coming soon!</h3>
<div>
<p>
Soon I hope to have made my first 'proper' game in Canvas and have it online.
</p>
<p>
- Currently learning the in's and out's of jQuery and Canvas.
- Designing websites for clients
- Doing exams in college 
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="tabs-2">

 <div id="accordion2">

<h3>Play Game 1</h3>
<div>
<p>
Game 1 is in development
<div align="center">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" align="center" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
 </canvas>
 </div>
 </p>
 </div>
 <h3>Play Game 2</h3>
 <div>
 <p>
 Game 2 is in development
 </p>
 </div>
 <h3>Play Game 3</h3>
 <div>
 <p>
 Game 3 is in development
 </p>

 </div>



 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
 hello

 </div>


  </div>




  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup is missing a closing `</div>`, so the 3<sup>rd</sup> tab's content is actually inside the 2<sup>nd</sup> (but hidden)!

Adding another `</div>` just before the `<div id="tabs-3">` will correct the problem.

There are other validation errors on this page, so I recommended running your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to correct *all* the errors.